# How to get all the values from appsettings key which starts with specific name and pass this to any array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

In my `web.config` file I have

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Service1URL1" value="http://managementService.svc/"/>
    <add key="Service1URL2" value="http://ManagementsettingsService.svc/HostInstances"/>
    ....lots of keys like above
</appSettings>
```

I want to get the value of key that starts with `Service1URL` and pass the value to `string[] repositoryUrls = { ... }` in my C# class. How can I achieve this?

I tried something like this but couldn't grab the values:

```
foreach (string key in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings)
{
    if (key.StartsWith("Service1URL"))
    {
        string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];            
    }

    string[] repositoryUrls = { value };
}
```

Either I am doing it the wrong way or missing something here. Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: your code looks bogus....  you define value inside an if statement, so its not going to be able to be used outside of that if.... then you define respositoryUrls inside the foreach, so it will get recreated each time ( not that it can get the "value" anyways )

Comment: A few options.  You could specify the number of service URL's in a separate key, and if they are contiguous series iterate through them that way with a for (int i=1;i<=serviceUrlCount;i++){serviceUrlvalue=Configurationmanager.AppSettings[String.Format("Service{0}Url")];//add value to list or array}.  Or, you could just keep iterating with a for/next until the key value pair isn't found.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I'd use a little LINQ:

```
string[] repositoryUrls = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys
                             .Where(key => key.StartsWith("Service1URL"))
                             .Select(key => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key])
                             .ToArray();
```

Comment: Hey thanks i added ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys instead of ConfigurationManager.AppSettings and its working fine thanks

Comment: This doesn't work. You can't run a where directly on AppSettings since it isn't IEnumerable<T>. You have to do an OfType or something similar

Comment: Will however work if you add the AllKeys as suggested by user 2133616

Answer (score 13):

You are overwriting the array for every iteration

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();
foreach (string key in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings)
        {
            if (key.StartsWith("Service1URL"))
            {
                string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
                values.Add(value);
            }

        }

string[] repositoryUrls = values.ToArray();
```

Comment: I tried this its looping through but not grabing any values i think Startwith is not working do you think anyother way of doing this? thanks anyway for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I defined a class to hold the variables I am interested in and iterate through the properties and look for something in the app.config to match.

Then I can consume the instance as I wish.
Thoughts?

```
public static ConfigurationSettings SetConfigurationSettings
{
    ConfigurationSettings configurationsettings = new   ConfigurationSettings();
    {
        foreach (var prop in  configurationsettings.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            string property = (prop.Name.ToString());
            string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[property];
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = configurationsettings.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
            propertyInfo.SetValue(configurationsettings, value, null);
        }
    }

    return configurationsettings;
 }
```